# access to DOM add dynamiclly, getScript, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use jQuery ajax to read context on my page dynamicly. But part of DOM is load in javaScript function call by getScript in ajax .done. But just after I load new content I need to get elements by class and use it in next function. Unfortunatly I can't find elements, that I create in javaScript function, and script with that function I call using jQuery getScript.

ok, my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(){
      var subpage = $(this).attr('data-subpage');
      var src = 'subpages/'+ subpage + '/' + subpage +'.php';
      var script = 'subpages/'+ subpage + '/js/' + subpage +'.js';

      $.ajax({
          url: src,
          context: document.body,
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(responseText){
              $('#text').html(responseText); // responseText has only container <div id="insideText"></div> that I use in one function and load there by html() several divs. One of this div has class 'translate'. I need it in function Translator
            }
      })
        .done(function(){
          $.getScript(script); // here I call script where I load several divs to #insideText
          Translator($('.active').attr('data-lang')).getTranslation() // part of function have to find all div.translate, but can't find it if they're load in script call in getScript. And this is a problem.
        })
    })
  })
```

I hope, I explaine my problem quite clear. If not, plaese ask, I'll try again.

There's some way to do that?

//update//

After this script, call by getScript I still have problem with second 'done':

```
  const Presenter = function(){
    var presented, show, fullDesc, cont;

    presented = [
      {
      url: 'demo/colorsGame/',
      name: 'Graj w kolorki!',
      desc: 'Graj w kolorki! Wybierz taki sam kolor, w jakim napisana jest nazwa wylosowanego koloru. Spiesz się, czas ucieka coraz szybciej i szybciej. Uważaj, bo mózg może cię oszukać i uznać za ważniejsze to, co jest napisane, a nie to co widzisz. Zobacz ile punktów jesteś w stanie zdobyć zanim popełnisz trzy błędy. Ćwicz swoją koncentrację.'
    },
    {
      url: 'demo/sampleUserProfile/',
      name: 'Sample User Profil',
      desc: 'Mała próbka możliwości reactJS. Wkonany z użyciem biblioteki reactJS, menadzera pakietów webpack oraz na środowisku nodeJS przykładowy profil użytkownika. Like-uj i obserwuj do woli, a jeśli chcesz, wypowiedz się pod profilem.'
    }
  ];

    show = function(url, desc, name) {
      fullDesc =
        "<a href ='" + url + "'>" +
          "<h1 class='translate'>" + name + "</h1>" +
        "</a>" +
        "<div>" +
          "<p class='translate'>" + desc + "</p>" +
        "</div>";

      cont =
        "<div id='webmin' class='clearfix'>" +
          "<div>" +
            fullDesc +
          "</div>" +
          "<div>" +
            "<iframe src='" + url + "' scrolling='no'>" +
              "ups, twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje ramek" +
            "</iframe>" +
          "</div>"+
        "</div>";

      return cont;
    };

    return {
      show: show,
      presented: presented
    }
  };

  display = function(){
    var len, url, name, desc;

    len = Presenter().presented.length;

    for(let i = 0; i <= len; i++){
      url = Presenter().presented[i].url;
      name = Presenter().presented[i].name;
      desc = Presenter().presented[i].desc;

      $('#insidetext.apps').append(Presenter().show(url, desc, name));
    }
  };
  display();
```

Hmm, I'm wondering, if iframe is not a problem here? And don't let script to be done to end?

Comment: getScript is just another ajax call and returns an xhr object which exposes done and fail methods. Use those methods to ensure your dom is properly loaded before trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getScript` is just another ajax call and returns an xhr object which exposes done and fail methods. Use those methods to ensure your dom is properly loaded before trying to access it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(){
      var subpage = $(this).attr('data-subpage');
      var src = 'subpages/'+ subpage + '/' + subpage +'.php';
      var script = 'subpages/'+ subpage + '/js/' + subpage +'.js';

      $.ajax({
          url: src,
          context: document.body,
          dataType: 'html'
      })
        .done(function(responseText){
             $('#text').html(responseText); 
             $.getScript(script).done(function() {
                 Translator($('.active').attr('data-lang')).getTranslation() ;
             }
        })
    })
})
```

Also, you should implement the .fail methods, in case your ajax requests fail.

Comment: Unfortunately it give nothing. Things in second 'done' don't want call. Even if I try just console.log("test), I don't get it.

Comment: Ah, I know why. It's because you supplied a success parameter and also attached a done method. Use one or the other. Updating answers

Comment: hmm, it's look like the problem is with script.js. I have several scripts. Much of them load now without a problem, and second 'done' work great. But one of scripts now. So , I update my question, I use iframe in this script, and maybe this is a problem...